# Put two parts of source code in the same line

Tags: code

How can I have this behavior in LaTeX please :

[image]

Two portions of code in the same line, separated by an arrow.

Comment: Well, either use a `tabular` or an `alignat` environment, however, that's mathmode. You could use `listings` too

Comment: Can I have some source code if it's possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In math mode use two `array` environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{lll}
r1 & = & 12\\
r2 & = & 34\\
r3 & = & r1+r2
\end{array}
\Leftrightarrow
\begin{array}{lll}
r3 & = & 12\\
r2 & = & 34\\
r2 & = & r3+r1
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

In text mode use `tabular` at both sides of  $\Leftrightarrow$:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
r1 & = & 12\\
r2 & = & 34\\
r3 & = & r1+r2
\end{tabular}
$\Leftrightarrow$
\begin{tabular}{lll}
r3 & = & 12\\
r2 & = & 34\\
r2 & = & r3+r1
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

For plain text is enough two `minipage`s:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{3cm}
Some text come here in a minipage
\end{minipage}
$\Leftrightarrow$
\begin{minipage}{3cm}
More dummy text to see the minipage
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]